# How to use svn tortoise by command in windows?

Tags: svn

I installed Tortoise-svn in my system(windows-7). i can use repository via Tortoise-svn application. but i want to use repository via command line how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseSVN 1.8 includes svn.exe command-line client. You can choose to install or not to install it in TortoiseSVN's installer.

Comment: i done with installation ,can you please give me reference link which have all command for SVN Tortoise ?

Comment: @abraz.in https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/index.html - TortoiseSVN Manual http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/ - SVNBook See commands reference at http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.html

Comment: Thanks i'll check it

Comment: its really help me